# Can't display to UI from within a void function - QT

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I am creating an app that will display sensor readings from an Arduino in the UI. I am receiving serial data through the serial port and would like to display it to an LCD number in the UI. However, I can't seem to modify the display on the LCD from my void function. 
Here is the portion in my mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::updateLCD(QString sensor) {
  qDebug() << "What's going on?";
  qDebug() << sensor;
  ui->label_5->setText(sensor);
  ui->lcdNumber_TMP->display(sensor);
}
```

Here is the portion in my header file:

```
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void updateLCD(QString);
```

I have been battling with this for quite a while. I don't receive any errors with the code as is, it just doesn't display the sensor output on the UI. Any ideas?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <string>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QList>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  //digital clock
  QTimer *timer=new QTimer(this); //for clock
  connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showTime()));
  timer->start();
  //TEMP DISPLAY
  ui->lcdNumber_TMP->display("------");
  //serial port
  device = new QSerialPort(this);
  serialBuffer = "";
  line = "";
  //Identify available ports
  bool device_available = false;
  QString device_port;
  foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    if(serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier() && serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier()) {
      if((serialPortInfo.productIdentifier() == device_product_id) && (serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier() == device_vendor_id)) {
        device_available = true; //device is available on this port
        device_port = serialPortInfo.portName();
      }
    }
  }
  //Open port, if available
  if(device_available) {
    qDebug() << "Found the device port...\n";
    device -> setPortName(device_port);
    device -> open(QSerialPort::ReadOnly);
    device -> setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    device -> setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    device -> setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    device -> setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    device -> setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    QObject::connect(device, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readSerial()));
  } else {
    qDebug() << "Couldn't find the correct port for the device.\n";
  }
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  if(device -> isOpen()) {
    device -> close(); //close serial port if it is open
  }
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::readSerial() {
  serialData = device -> readAll();
  serialBuffer += QString::fromStdString(serialData.toStdString());
  QStringList bufferSplit = serialBuffer.split(",");
  serialBuffer = "";
  line=bufferSplit[0];
  MainWindow::updateLCD(bufferSplit[0]);
}

void MainWindow::updateLCD(QString sensor) {
  qDebug() << "What's going on?";
  qDebug() << sensor;
  ui->label_5->setText(sensor);
  ui->lcdNumber_TMP->display(sensor);
}

void MainWindow::showTime() {
  QTime time=QTime::currentTime(); //create time
  QString time_text=time.toString("hh : mm : ss"); //format time
  ui->DigitalClock->setText(time_text); //make label display time
}
```

Comment: What do you get in the qDebug?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I assume the main thread is in a loop. The GUI will not be updated in the loop even though you call `ui->label_5->setText(sensor);` ...

Comment: in the qDebug it acts the way I expect it to- prints "What is going on?" and the sensor output.

Comment: The code that shows is not the most optimal but workable, I think the problem is the frame it sends, you could show an example of the code that generates the frame in the arduino.

Comment: The Arduino code is a simple serial print loop with a 1s delay. I am just using it to simulate a sensor output. I thought I was covering my bases with qDebug to check if I was actually reading from the serial port as well as attempting to display the serial data in both the LCD number display and in a text label... but maybe it has to do with the way in which the serial data is being read? or being produced?

        `void setup() {
          Serial.begin(9600);    
        }

        void loop() {
          Serial.println("50.03,");
        }`

Comment: RE : @eyllanesc

Comment: @YelenaRandall where is the delay? I tried your code and it works obviously with an inappropriate behavior because the data that I send from the arduino is random, I'm going to test your arduino code, what version of Qt do you use?

Comment: @eyllanesc - I use QT Creator 4.4.1. 

Sorry, I condensed the Arduino code and accidentally deleted the delay. The delay is in the void loop() after the print command as delay(1000);.

When you ran the code it was able to display the serial output in the UI?

Comment: One thing is the version of Qt Creator, and another is the version of Qt.

Comment: @YelenaRandall Try with this code: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48648573  .With the arduino code that you provide, I can display the data correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, so I've tried to run the code you manipulated (by the way, thank you very much for reworking that), and it still doesn't display in the UI. My only guess now is that the version of Qt is not doing what it's supposed to be. What version are you working in?

Comment: have you changed device product_id and the device vendor id? Have you tried with the arduino code that you showed me?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, I use the device product id and device vendor id for the specific device I have connected. That device is running the same arduino code that I gave you. By the way, this device is a knock-off version of an Arduino Uno (not sure why that would affect anything, but thought I'd mention it)

Comment: When you execute the code that you get in the output window? I have placed qDebug to see the processing, you could share that text with me.

Comment: @eyllanesc I restarted QT, and now your code is displaying sensor output in the UI!

Comment: How does Qt restart? ;D

Comment: @eyllanesc Just quit the program and opened it again, and things decided to work....! 
Now able to get my UI displaying sensor readings as well... thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

QWidgets like (your MainWindow) only repaint themselves on the screen once a QPaintEvent is being processed. Judging from your description it sounds like the event loop (QEventLoop) is not being run.

A void function by itself is not limiting in any way. The question rather is whether the Qt event loop is freely running. Assuming your started it with QCoreApplication::exec() you should return to it after processing the serial port signal.

Comment: I have updated my post to include all of my code. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Qt event loop." I can't wrap my brain around the fact that the clock updates on the UI, but that my sensor data doesn't. Is it because I'm not actually calling the readALL in that same function?

Comment: There is no call to QTimer::setInterval(). As the default value is 0 you'll have the timer firing as soon as events are processed again. As a result you may receive nothing but clock updates. Try timer->setInterval(500) as a start.